# Bound ComboBox fill values from reference table

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

First off this is a employee shift log application.

The employee logs in and selects machines they will operate. This is generally two machines but if someone doesn't show up they may log into as many as 4.
I have a `WinForm` that has a `ComboBox` bound to a field in the `Shift_Log` table.

My problem is the Combobox is bound to the Shiftlog_ID field and shows the operator_id instead of the operator name. The drop down shows employee names but once selected it displays the ID. I need it to always display the name of the employee. 
I am thinking I'm expecting to much. Do I need to unbind the combo and write code in the cmbOperator_SelectedValueChange_Changed event to store the ID to the shiftlog field. Then I would have to put code in the form load to display the name of the current employee based on the ID stored in the record.
I have done a bunch in `VB.Net` this is my first `C#` project. Didn't think it would be that hard. Definitely a learning curve. If someone could just point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.
Thank you.

[image: Shift Log Form]

Comment: This is more a description of the operations. What is your question?

Comment: Very nice explanation of your program but what is the problem?

Comment: I need the operator combo box to display the employee name from the employee table But store the employee ID in the shift log. Right now it shows the I’d but the drop down shows the name. In this case NW is the ID.

Comment: Post the code that fills the `ComboBox.DataSource`, then. Someone will come by and fix it. If what's wrong is visible and can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I dragged and dropped the field from the Data Source tab to the screen the IDE added a binding to the text value. Then when I updated the combo box through the control smart tag it added a second binding. A coworker noticed that I had two bindings as soon as the first binding to the text value was deleted it worked. BTW in order to get it to work on the first record I had moved the binding to the FormLoad. Now it shows the operator name and saves the ID and does not give a error when navigating between records. Thanks for all your input.

cmbOperator.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", this.shift_LogBindingSource, "Operator", true));

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a couple different ways to fill the combo box. The first was through using the smart tag. Selecting the employee table as the source, Name as display, and Initials as Value. I thought maybe the Selected Value would be the field selectedvalue would be stored too. Second I tried code.

```
        private void fillcmbOperator()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.LazerMaintenance_Conn))
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT Operators.Initials, Operators.Name " +
                       "FROM Operators WHERE Operators.Active_Ind = 'True'";

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                conn.Open();

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "dsOperators");

                cmbOperator.ValueMember = "Initials";
                cmbOperator.DisplayMember = "Name";
                cmbOperator.DataSource = ds.Tables["dsOperators"];

                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // write exception info to log or anything else
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured! : " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW the printer selection on the DGV works great. I completely set it up through the Collections "Edit columns" pop-up.

[Collections "Edit columns" pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVC0T.png)

Comment: Make an Alias for the Fields that have a dotted name. `Operators.Initials` should be `Initials`, `Operators.Name` should be `Name`. This also because you can't have a `.DisplayMember = "Operators.Name";`, with a dotted field name. It won't work. Of course, the same rule applies to `.ValueMember`. To retrieve the `SelectedValue` (and/or `SelectedItem`), use something like this: `ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedValue);`